# Page blank when js: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm writing an Rspec test supported by Capybara and Poltergeist. When `js: true` is enabled for the test the resulting page is blank. HTML content is just

`<html><head><base href='http://www.hostname.local' /></head><body></body></html>`.

If I remove `js: true` content appears.

- Rails: 4.2
- Phantom JS: 2.1.1
- Capybara gem: 2.11.0
- Poltergeist gem: 1.12.0

In rails_helper.rb
`Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`

Test:

```
context 'as company_manager' do
    before(:each) do
      @company_manager = create(:user, :company_manager, company: company)
      login_as @company_manager, scope: :user
    end

    context 'show page' do
      it 'should be able to view tenants grid and sort', js: true do
        visit company_lot_path(company_id: company.id, id: lot.id)
        save_and_open_page
        # test cases are here
      end
    end
end
```

Screenshots are blank as well. I can't figure out why content is blank when javascript is enabled.

Comment: Try sleeping a few seconds between visit and save_and_open_page just to see if anything shows up. Also enabling the `:debug` option in your driver registration - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization -should give more clues to what is happening.  Also, please add any other Capybara configuration you have done to your question (app_host, etc).

Comment: Just to be sure, you do require `rails_helper` in your spec instead of `spec_helper` file?